# How to match the following output using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl

The room information:

```
singleRoom (male): 0x3
singleRoom (famle): 0x0
```

I want to match the second line of the output: `singleRoom (male): 0x3` and get the value `0x3` which is hexadecimal. how to achieve it without using the "`*`" pattern?

Comment: I think it's due time to read the "Mastering Regular Expressions" book by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl or some other introductory course on regexes for your questions on this topic more and more feel like falling into the "homework" category...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^singleRoom \(male\): (0x[a-fA-F0-9]+)$`

Comment: actually, between (male): 0x3 there are some spaces or tabs

Comment: Good call, @GlennJackman So, including the variable whitespace: `^singleRoom \(male\):\s+(0x[[:xdigit:]]+)$` Note I also escaped the brackets around 'male', so it's not a capture group... Now find some regex tutorials!!

Comment: @Xoph I find it nice to use `[(]` instead of `\(`; decreasing the backslash count is always a good thing. (Both are Tcl metacharacters though, so it remains important to put the RE in braces.)